How to trigger navigationManager.LocationChanged upon clicking links that change URL fragment or hash in Blazor 8?
In a Blazor 7 web assembly project, _navigationManager_LocationChanged of the following code is being triggered after clicking the links (Login, Sign Up, or Forgot Password). The same event is not being triggered in Blazor 8.
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
@implements IDisposable

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<a href="#login">Login</a> |
<a href="#signup"> Sign Up</a> |
<a href="#forgotpassword">Forgot Password</a>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _navigationManager.LocationChanged += _navigationManager_LocationChanged;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    void _navigationManager_LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("_navigationManager_LocationChanged: " + e.Location);
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _navigationManager.LocationChanged -= _navigationManager_LocationChanged;
    }
}


Agreed.  It's a definite change in functionality.  Have you posted a comment on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues ?

@Arvin You want to navigate into another page ? Or to navigate within one page (anchors)? I am just asking because if u want to navigate to different page then you dont have to use #. If you want me to take a closer look then create a repro project and share it through github.

@Kebechet . i want to navigate to another page within the same blazor assembly. i am also using a custom router that uses hash (#)

@MrCakaShaunCurtis i've looked everywhere but nobody seemed to notice this issue. i plan to post this on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues if this cannot be resolved here.

your code worked in my side, I test in blazor web assembly .net 8 project.... https://i.sstatic.net/xVvp25ui.png  I also test it in blazor web app server side rendering  app and it also worked if I have @rendermode InteractiveServer in my component..

If I put the code in Home.raozr, then I can reproduce your issue, if I put the code in counter.razor, then everything worked well....It might due to that when in the home page , the navigation doesn't occur indeed.

Consider using NavLink instead of a. Maybe it could help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#navlink-component

No difference.  It's not where the problem lies.
